# ZeroConf -- should I include dot(.) in the end of the address?

Tags: networking, bonjour, zeroconf

I'm trying to access my machine through ZeroConf. Which address is correct?

`machine.local` or `machine.local.` ?

Answer (score 3):

`machine.local.` is the recommended and "correct" way.

The final dot makes it an *absolute* fully qualified host name [just like in Unix when the leading slash (***`/`***) makes a path an absolute path].

Without that final dot the host name will become *relative* to the DNS search domain(s).

**Example:**

- Your DNS search domains contains `apple.com` as well as `microsoft.com`.
- You look for a host name `machine.local`.
- The resulting list of found names could be `machine.local.` as well as `machine.local.apple.com.` and `machine.local.microsoft.com.` (assuming that within Apple's and Microsoft's domains there are sub-domains `local` with hostnames `machine`, which may be not-so likely. Maybe I should think of better examples...)

---

See also here: [Trailing Dots in Domain Names](http://www.dns-sd.org/TrailingDotsInDomainNames.html).